# Azure - is it possible to share account with co-workers

Tags: azure

A group of friends and I are working on an private project and are considering hosting it on Azure.

I have an account on Azure and will be the one controlling the costs.

Is it possible to assign a pool of resources (e.g. Functions + database) to another user(s), preferably also assigning a cost limit for it to avoid things exploding?

Comment: To limit cost, I would just set them up as read-only so they can see how everything is set up, but wouldn't be able to provision any new services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give them access to a subscription / resource group / resource by going to e.g. the subscription and clicking on Access Control (IAM).

There you can enter their email address, and give them the role needed. Reader for read-only, Contributor for Read/Write, and Owner for Read/Write + access management. There are a bunch of others too. [More about Role-based access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure)

I am not aware of a way to limit cost for individual users, though you can for example setup [Billing alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-set-up-alerts).

Answer (score 2):

You can use ARM policies to limit the types of resources that can be used. As an example, you can deny the use of certain very expensive VMs to a group of users. Some samples of these policy templates can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/json-samples)

As stated in other answers, you can assign access to others on various levels. You can assign to "live" accounts (Hotmail,outlook,live.com etc) but as part of your subscription you can also create an Azure Active Directory instance on which you can create users. You would also want to use this AAD to create service accounts in the future, register applications for authentication, etc.